# Appium: Element locators SOMETIMES not found in Android Web View

Tags: javascript, appium

I am working on an E2E test automation project on a hybrid Android app. The home screen is the web view part and sometimes, the element locators are not found. When I refresh the app or something, it works well again. What could be causing this problem and how can I avoid this?

Currently, my current work-around is just refreshing the app manually. I guess if I can automate this process or just clicking on an icon on the home screen with exact coordinates, those could be some solutions as well, although they are very bad approaches.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.